# ActiveAdmin - show attributes from association model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have `Registration` model that `has_many` players `{Player}`. Registration has registerer's first name field and last name field, and a `Player` has such fields as `name`, `date_of_birth`, `club`. From users's perspective it is possible to add up to 3 players on the registration form so a `Registration` will always have up to 3 players.

Now, in Active Admin on `Registration` Index view I would like to show those 3 players' attributes, somehow like this.

Registration

```
First_name | Last name | Players           |
                         Name : ...     
                         Date of birth: ...
                         Club :...

                         Name: ...
                         Date of birth: ...
                         Club :...
```

Or maybe like this.

```
First_name | Last name | Player name | Player date of birth | ...  | Player name | Player date of birth |
```

Though I think the first way would be better.

So my `Registration` can have max 3 players associated with it and I would like to display players attributes on Registration index page.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a method that displays the player details with line separators

```
def show_players
  players.map do |player|
    "name: #{player.name}\ndob: #{player.date_of_birth}\nclub:#{player.club}\n"
  end.join("\n")
end
```

Then in your admin index block include the method

```
column :show_players
```

Comment: Where would I define this method? I defined it in `index do` block but it doesn't display anything.

Comment: No, it's a Registration model method... put it in `app/models/registration.rb` .  The `index do` block only needs the one column line

Comment: It's a registration method like the other registration methods `:first_name` and `:last_name`... those are all sent to the registration object and now `show_players` will be sent to the registration object, so that's why `show_players` is a registration object (instance) method.